# Audio not working Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

my audio is not working anymore.
I'm going mad. I tried all the solutions proposed (reinstall alsa, pulse) pavucontrol and so.
If I choose HDMI output I can hear the sound...

DO you have any tips?

Many many thanks

R

Comment: Does your PC have internal speakers that usually play sound? Are you HDMI-ing to a monitor or a TV? Can you check the result of `aplay -l` please? If you run through this list where do you get stuck? https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-sound-through-hdmi-in-external-monitor-in-ubuntu/

Comment: I noticed that sometimes the problem does not happen if I suspend and resume the laptop...and yes I have internal speakers and I HDMI-ing the monitor